# Objective C Syntax: addTarget on UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, syntax

I'm currently working on an app where the user has the option to either swipe through data, or use a button to go through the data. I'm having trouble understanding how to combine two bits of code.

Here is the code I'm using for swiping:

```
- (void)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{

if ([questions hasPrevQuestion] == YES) {
    [self vorige:nil];

    }    
}
```

(the `[self vorige:nil];` is calling the method for the button, so the swiping and the button have the same behavior)
and I need to somehow incorporate this code which applies to the button:

```
-(void)animationDidEndOnAnswer {

[vorigeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(newQuestion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

I think it's pretty simple, but I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to call the swiping method place of the button here...I'm thinking it's simple because I found this example in the UIGestureRecognizer class reference:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

but being new to objective-c, I don't really know what to do with this. any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action` is the code equivalent of binding a button action to a method like you do when you ctrl-drag from a button to an IBAction in Interface Builder.

So if your method is called `vorige:` and you want it to be called when the button is tapped, you would say:

```
[vorigeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(vorige:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But I don't know why you would want to do that as a result of an animation - you normally would set the button action once when the view is loaded, not change it during an animation.

Answer (score 1):

Nick's solution is good.

if you want to call the same method for the swiping & the tap on your button, you can tweak your swipeRight like this:

```
- (void)goThrougtData:(id)sender
{
  if( [sender isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]] ) {
    // swipe specific code
  }
  else if( [sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] ) {
    // tap specific code
  }
  if ([questions hasPrevQuestion] == YES) {
    [self vorige:nil];
  }    
}
```

and in your init method, you add

```
[mySwipeRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(vorige:)];
[vorigeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(vorige:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```